# When is Fēngyún-3C planned to launch?

Tags: launch

When is Fēngyún-3C planned to launch?

The [CEOS/ESA EO Handbook](http://database.eohandbook.com/database/missionsummary.aspx?missionID=368) states July 2013, but this was last updated October 2012, and I don't think it's actually been launched.  [WMO-sat.info](http://www.wmo-sat.info/oscar/satellites/view/115) says >= 2013, but is not specific either.  Googling Fēngyún-3C or FY-3C does not lead me to more up-to-date information.  I don't know any Chinese, so perhaps there is more current information accessible to those who do through the [CMA NSMC website](http://www.nsmc.cma.gov.cn/NewSite/NSMC/Home/Index.html).

Comment: Google translate?

Comment: @Undo Trying that as well, but significant information may be lost in translation, and searching is particularly tricky.

Comment: @gerrit, I voted to close because this is a transient question (answered today, wrong tomorrow). Think it would better fit into either Meta or the Pod Bay. As you well know, a launch can be planned a hundred times.

Comment: @gerrit - in addition, this looks like a forum-type question. SE ain't it.

Comment: @DeerHunter That's worth a discussion, [see this meta question](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/237/33).

Comment: I can't find a credible site that lists it as anything but 2013. I don't think there is an answer to this, just a lot of speculation.

Comment: No official date yet, but I've found [this thread on NASA Space Flight Forum](http://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=30407.0) that seems to be updated frequently enough on the status of the mission.

Comment: @TildalWave I already linked the OSCAR page in my question.

Comment: Oh, duh, I read the last forum post as being from 8 February, but it's actually from 2 August, so as recent as it gets.

Comment: I liked the comment another closer added.  This is too transient in time.  A year from now, this will be a meaningless question.

Like when will the F9-Cassipe mission launch.  Sept 5 2013 is the date.  What does the question mean on Sept 6 then?
